# AWS CodeDeploy & ECS - Routing traffic to N services in an AWS ECS cluster that use CodeDeploy's Blue/Green deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-code-deploy

I have an AWS ECS cluster that runs N public facing services, each service runs a different dockerized application and is deployed using a Blue/Green deployment managed by AWS CodeDeploy.

HTTPS traffic is routed to my services using an application load balancer and host based routing rules (Each service has a unique subdomain on a common root domain, one.example.com, two.example.com, etc...).

All of my infrastructure is managed through Terraform. Below is the code from a module I created to configure the required target groups and listener rules for CodeDeploy to perform a Blue/Green deployment. Each service has it's own instance of this module.

```
# Blue/Green networking configuration for ECS service

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "blue" {
  name                 = "${var.env}-${var.service_name}-blue"
  port                 = 80
  protocol             = "HTTP"
  vpc_id               = var.vpc_id
  deregistration_delay = 60

  health_check {
    path     = var.health_check_path
    protocol = "HTTP"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "green" {
  name                 = "${var.env}-${var.service_name}-green"
  port                 = 80
  protocol             = "HTTP"
  vpc_id               = var.vpc_id
  deregistration_delay = 60

  health_check {
    path     = var.health_check_path
    protocol = "HTTP"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "service_host_rule" {
  listener_arn = var.https_listener_arn

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.blue.arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = [var.service_domain_name]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the listener rule I've created for the services subdomain currently only forwards traffic to the blue target group.

```
# deployment.tf in ECS service module
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "this" {
  app_name               = var.code_deploy.app_name
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"
  deployment_group_name  = var.ecs_service_name
  service_role_arn       = var.code_deploy.service_role.arn

  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events  = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }

  dynamic "blue_green_deployment_config" {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
    }

    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action                           = "TERMINATE"
      termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 10
    }
  }

  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type   = "BLUE_GREEN"
  }

  ecs_service {
    cluster_name = var.cluster_name
    service_name = var.ecs_service_name
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      target_group {
        # The Blue target group created in the above module
        name = var.alb_target_groups.blue.name
      }

      target_group {
        # The Green target group created in the above module
        name = var.alb_target_groups.green.name
      }

      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [var.alb_listener_arn]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my CI/CD pipeline this terraform is run, creating the target groups, listener rule and deployment group. Once the terraform has run the deployment is started through the AWS CLI `aws deploy create-deployment ...`.

This works fine for the first deployment of the service, once it's completed all traffic is routed to the `green` target group and the tasks running in the `blue` group are terminated.

Then when deploying a new version for the second time, CodeDeploy returns an error message:

```
The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Primary taskset target group must be behind listener arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xxxxxx:xxxxxx:listener-rule/app/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.
```

I believe this is because CodeDeploy looks for the `blue` target group, expecting current traffic to be routing to it. But instead because of the state the last deploy left the service in the next deploy will fail. Is there something wrong in my configuration? or am I missing a manual step that needs to be completed once a deploy finishes?

Edit:

To give more clarity on how my infrastructure is setup:

```
infrastructure/
 |- modules/
 |  |- ecs-service/
 |  |  |- modules/
 |  |  |  |- blue-green-config/
 |  |  |  |  |- main.tf  
 |  |  |- main.tf
 |  |  |- deployment.tf
```

The ECS service module creates its own instance of a Blue/Green configuration module.

Comment: Is this all part of the same module?

Comment: @MarkoE they are separate modules, although they are nested.  So each service module that needs to be deployed using Blue/Green will create an instance of the first module.

Comment: There are ways to do this I think, but without more context it's hard to tell. Can you share the way you are invoking modules?

Comment: @MarkoE I've edited my question to show how the file structure is setup

Comment: Great, and does your module have any outputs defined, the one where target groups are defined?

Comment: @MarkoE That module outputs the arn and name of both the blue and green target groups.

Answer (score 0):

Some details are still missing (e.g. output names), but what I would suggest is instead of using variable names in `deployment.tf` for target groups to use the `ecs-service` module outputs. This way, you would tell terraform to create an implicit dependency between the resources created by the child module and the resources created in the root module. For example:

```
module "ecs_service" {
  source = "./modules/blue-green-config"

  ... rest of the variables go here ...
}
```

In the `deployment.tf` there would be the following change (removed all the things that would stay the same):

```
# deployment.tf in ECS service module
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "this" {
.
.
.

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      target_group {
        name = module.ecs_service.blue_target_group_name # <---- example, since the output names are not in the question
      }

      target_group {
        name = module.ecs_service.green_target_group_name # <---- example, since the output names are not in the question
      }

      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [var.alb_listener_arn]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Besides those two implicit dependencies, I would strongly suggest creating outputs for `listener_arns` as well as for the ECS service and cluster name and using those instead of variables. One thing to reconsider as well is:

```
  dynamic "blue_green_deployment_config" {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
    }

    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action                           = "TERMINATE"
      termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 10
    }
  }
```

because it seems that this is a `dynamic` block without specifying any conditions and `content` for that block, which kind of renders the `dynamic` keyword useless.